# OpenCV - Unsupported format or combination of formats error

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have created the program from this tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html
I added my own images in .jpg format. But some images in one directory ( I have 3 different directories with different photos of persons) are probably wrong and I don't know why. I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (In the Fisherfaces method all input samples (training images) must be of equal size! Expected 921600 pixels, but was 1228800 pixels.) in cv::Fisherfaces::train, file C:\buildslaves64\win64_amdocl\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\contrib\src\facerec.cpp, line 564
```

I use VS C++ 2012 and vc11 libs from openCV 2.4.7. Can someone help me with this problem?

[image: Good image]
[image: Bad image]

Comment: Could you upload two of your images (one good image and the other one from the images that have the program to report an error).

Comment: I edited post. First image is ok second one not. Also all images from my front camera in my samsung s6 are recognized as wrong and raise same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was a mistake in size of images. Program expected 921600 (it is 1280px x 720px) and the wrong images have wrong size. Their size was greater or less but not equal. I formatted all of them to 1280x720 and it started work.
All training images must have same size.